# TeXStudio: high CPU usage after version 2.6.2

Tags: editors

How can I fix that problem?
All versions after 2.6.2 increase the CPU usage and the fan goes like crazy.

Thanks

P.S. I have already tried to not use spelling correction, yet the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

OK, just for future reference. If you have installed the whole version of TeX, say via MikTeX, then TeXStudio needs some time to check all packages. It will use mpm.exe (miktex package manager) to do that.

The only solution is to wait. It just does it once :)